# Validate based on 2nd value of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an multidimensional array which is consisting of filename and file format like

```
[["awardees.png", "png"], ["history.png", "png"]]
```

I want to validate whether both the file format are equal or not?

Comment: Do you want to check if the second item of the first array is equal to the second array's second item or whether the first item of each array contains the second item?

Comment: And for the first case, does this need to work for just two files or can the array contain many files that all need to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `every()` and compare the second element of each array with the second element of first array.

```js
const arr = [["awardees.png", "png"],["history.png", "png"],["karnat.jpg", "jpg"]] ;

console.log(arr.every(([v1,v2]) => arr[0][1] === v2))
```

#### For IE

```js
const arr = [["awardees.png", "png"],["history.png", "png"]] ;

console.log(arr.every(function(x){

  return arr[0][1] === x[1] 

}))
```

Comment: does it works in IE

Comment: @AtalShrivastava arrow functions and destructuring is not supported in IE

Comment: sorry why false when both file format are same

Comment: @AtalShrivastava Fixed that bro.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
const arr = [["awardees.png", "png"], ["history.png", "png"]];
const match = arr[0][1] == arr[1][1];
console.log(match);
```

If the array has multiple elements (nested arrays):

```js
const arr = [["awardees.png", "png"], ["history.png", "png"], ["dog.png", "png"]];
const match = arr.every(([, v]) => v == arr[0][1]);
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check all formats with the first element.

```js
var array = [["awardees.png", "png"], ["history.png", "png"]],
    same = array.every((b, _, [a]) => a[1] === b[1]);

console.log(same);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question properly you can split the extension from first value and match with the second value

```js
let data = [["awardees.png", "png"],["history.png", "png"]] 

data.forEach(value => {
  let fileExt = value[0].split('.')[1]
  console.log(fileExt === value[1])
})
```

In case you want all the inner arrays must have the same extension you can simply change `forEach` to `every`

Answer (score 0):

Capture the file extension using regex, then iterate over every entry in the array to check whether its equal to the file extension or not.

```js
const arr = [
 ["awardees.png", "png"], 
 ["history.png", "png"],
 ["demo.png1", "png"],
];

// Regex for capturing file extension in 1st capturing group
const pattern = /\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/i;

const res = arr.map(x => {

 // Compare the captured group's value with array element
 if (x[0].match(pattern)[1] === x[1]) {
  return true;
 }
  
 return false;
});

console.log(res);
```